# Ruby Wait for SubProcess to Finish

Tags: ruby

I'm forking another ruby script because there's no good way to catch exceptions on that script and it occasionally errors out. If and when it finishes and/or errors out I want to re-spawn it and let it continue where it left off from. Here's my script:

```
def runit(number)
  r = spawn("cmd /c ruby c:\\bot\\myscript.rb", [:out, :err] => ["c:\\bot\\myscript#{number}.log", 'w'],  :new_pgroup => true)
  Process.detach(r)
  r
end

def runme
  r = runit(1)
  Process.wait(r)
end

something = "nothing"
while something == 'nothing'
  runme
end
```

My problem is that when the subprocess errors out so does the main process. This causes the loop to end.

**How can I fork a process and restart it in case it dies or errors out?**